# Is there a way to use Apache Velocity with .properties file?

Tags: java, velocity

I've a JSON template in a property file in my project. Is there a way I can use Apache Velocity for embedding dynamic content without using .vm file ?

I've something like:

```
 template = [ { "name" : "$firstName $lastName" } ];
```

in my .properties file. Now when I parse this JSON and store the corresponding value I want to use Velocity so that I can get firstName and lastName dynamically.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking--if you can change the extension used for a template file?

Comment: No, I'm not looking for changing the file extension I just want to use `.properties` instead of `.vm` .

Comment: So you want to change the extension.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking how to load a Velocity template from a value in a properties file instead of from a template file.

You can do this by writing a custom [ResourceLoader](https://velocity.apache.org/engine/releases/velocity-1.5/apidocs/org/apache/velocity/runtime/resource/loader/ResourceLoader.html) for Velocity. The resource loader would parse a [properties file](https://velocity.apache.org/engine/releases/velocity-1.5/apidocs/org/apache/velocity/runtime/resource/loader/ResourceLoader.html) and return the template which is stored as a property value.

For this to work, you have to [configure Velocity](https://velocity.apache.org/engine/releases/velocity-1.7/developer-guide.html#Configuring_Resource_Loaders) to use your resource loader instead of the one you are currently using.

Comment: Thanks for your response, will give it a try and let you know.